# Printing array value from a hash in perl

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I am new to perl and this thing is driving me nuts. I have a hash as below

```
%temp = (
  a_collection => [\%first, \%second]
)
```

I want to get the array elements out as a string  so i can use them as args in the loop. I have below code

```
foreach $item (@{$temp{'a_collection'}})
{
  <convert to json> $item  #convert each of the above hash to a json blob
  <write to file> $file    #write first blob to file "first.json" and so on
}
```

I got the convert to json part. I can print it to stdout. Now i want to write it to a file. Here the $file should have name "first" and "second". So the loop will create two files with names of the hash variables which are there in the above hash. I want the filenames to match so i can keep track of whats getting created.

Edit :
The basic premise is simple. Whatever i do, be it json encoding etc, i want the hash variable names as a string. So in the array above, i can have a hash with any name \%somename, in the loop i want the actual string "somename" in a   different variable. As above, i can use this string as file name that gets created . I cannot change the above hash structure. Its just there, created by someone else, i can only access it.

Thanks

Comment: Your loop does not match the data structure you posted above it. What's the *actual* code you're using?

Comment: @user775093 what you actually trying? Are you referencing the hash inside the hash of array? If you want to do this, see below answer. Or anything else edit your post?

Comment: You've completely changed the question, and it's still just as unclear as it was before, but the basic premise of my answer is still the same: hash keys.

Comment: @user775093 why you changed your question? You should have asked a new one.

Comment: Because i was able to get the first part of what i wanted. I was referring to the hash variables anyways. The basic question is still the same.. I cannot change anything in the structure above . So i cant make "first" and "second" as hash keys. If i was allowed to do that I wouldnt have asked the question.

Comment: So, why didn't you kept the whole question before, so that we can understand your requirement well from the begining. In this case it became XY problem because of uncomplete question.

Comment: I will say why aren't you creating the filenames at the begining where you are declaring(or someone else declared) `%first` and `%second` hashes. If you would have done that, then there will be no need to get string out of your hash name.

Comment: @user775093 You can't create hash keys named `first` and `second`, but you can create _hashes_ named `%first` and `%second`? Explain to me how that works.

Comment: in that case of course i can hard code the filenames etc. Of course i can do anything i want if it was possible. But its not and hence the question of how to get the  names as string. If someone else adds a new hash in the file, i dont want to change my code to get that in json too. The same loop should work no matter what. The answer to a problem is not changing the problem..

Comment: Why don't you post your actual code instead of a contrived little example so that we can see where the data is coming from? (As I requested in my **first comment**...)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %first  = (foo => 2, bar => 3, bat => 5);
my %second = (baz => 7, quux => 11);
my %temp   = (a_collection => [\%first, \%second]);

for my $href (@{$temp{a_collection}}) {
    for my $key (keys(%$href)) {
        print "$key: $href->{$key}\n";
    }
}
```

This is the output produced:

```
bar: 3
foo: 2
bat: 5
quux: 11
baz: 7
```

---

Edit after new information was provided:

```
my %first  = (foo => 2, bar => 3, bat => 5);
my %second = (baz => 7, quux => 11);
my %temp   = (first => \%first, second => \%second);

for my $key (keys(%temp)) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

---

Edit after yet more new information was provided:

```
use JSON::XS;

my %first  = (foo => 2, bar => 3, bat => 5);
my %second = (baz => 7, quux => 11);
my %temp   = (first => \%first, second => \%second);

for my $key (keys(%temp)) {
    open(my $fh, '>', "$key.json") or die $!;
    print $fh encode_json($temp{$key});
    close($fh);
}
```

Contents of `first.json`:

```
{"foo":2,"bat":5,"bar":3}
```

Contents of `second.json`:

```
{"quux":11,"baz":7}
```

Comment: That is not what i want . The output should be "first" and "second"

Comment: Then you should probably create a hash with keys called `first` and `second`.